# Javascript read numbers from text file loop until no more numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file with some numbers that I need to extract from different lines. The sequence of numbers is not always the same so I need to loop until there's no more numbers. line example below.

Numbers: `1,2,3,4(222.000,222.000),(333.000,222.000),.....,`

Need to create a loop here (below)

```
output1=output1.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[7]).join("\n");
output2=output2.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[8]).join("\n");
output3=output3.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[9]).join("\n");
output4=output4.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[10]).join("\n");
output5=output5.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[11]).join("\n");
output6=output6.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[12]).join("\n");
output7=output7.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/).map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[13]).join("\n");
```

Comment: Please be more clear. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: need to take the code lines above and loop it.. for each variable... it will assign on number from the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to return `.split()`, `.map()`, `.filter()` calls on string input. Create an object having property name, values pairs reflecting index to set at bracket notation as property and string input as value. Use `.forEach()` to iterate array of objects, calling function at each object.

```
function filter(str, index) { 
  return str.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /Numbers/)
         .map(line => line.split(/,|\(|\)/)
         .filter(number => number != "")[index]).join("\n") 
};

[output1, output2, output3, output4, output5, output6, output7] = 
[{7:output1}, {8:output2}, {9:output3}, {10:output4}
, {11:output5} {12:output6}, {13:output7}]
.map(o => filter.apply(null, Object.entries(o).pop()));
```